# Adjoining subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be an extension of $F$ and $\alpha\in K$. Let $F(\alpha)$ be the smallest subfield in $K$ which contains $F$ and $\alpha$.
Let $S:= \{q\in K: q= f(\alpha)/g(\alpha) f,g\in F[\alpha] ,g(\alpha)\neq0\}$
So my question is $F(\alpha)=S?$ I didn't understand the answer to the question named "Algebraic field extensions: Why $k(\alpha)=k[\alpha]?$ ".

Comment: You're right : $S = F(\alpha)$. Indeed, if $L$ is field over $F$ containing $\alpha$ then $L$ should contain $P(\alpha)$ for any $P \in F[X]$ and since $L$ is a subfield, it contains $1/P(\alpha)$ if $P(\alpha) \not = 0$. Thus $L$ contains $S$. Now, $F[\alpha]$ denotes the smallest subring in $K$ which contains $F$ and $\alpha$. Surprisingly, $F[\alpha]$ is a subfield if $\alpha$ **is algebraic over** $F$,  so $F(\alpha) = F[\alpha]$ in that case.

Comment: @Halbaroth If $\alpha\in C$ set of complex numbers and $F$ is any subfield of $C$. Then is $\alpha$ algebraic over $F ?$

Comment: Not at all! Take $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha = \pi$. It is well known that $\pi$ is not algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @Halbaroth Is $Q(\pi)=Q[\pi]?$

Comment: No. $F[\alpha]$ is a field over $F$ if and only if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: Can you prove the fact that $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$ if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115461/discussion-between-charlie-and-halbaroth).